# Alfresco faceted search - type facet

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I know it is possible to create custom facets [from a document property](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/filtered-search-custom.html), and it works well.

But is it possible to create a facet based on the **node type title** ?

With the following standard model, there would be a facet with values named **Folder** and **Content**.

```
<type name="cm:folder">
   <title>Folder</title>
   <parent>cm:cmobject</parent>
   <archive>true</archive>
...
<type name="cm:content">
   <title>Content</title>
   <parent>cm:cmobject</parent>
   <archive>true</archive>
   <properties>
   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be an Alfresco platform focused answer rather than a share oriented answer.

It is possible to facet on the TYPE field. 
This will be the QName of the type (e.g. cm:folder).

The title you really want to display will be language specific so should use this as a key for localisation.

So, you can do the roll up via the API but would have to customise share faceting to display the correct thing. I believe this is possible as share faceting is extendible and configuration driven. I also suspect it is not easy to do and configure - it is not something that is normally changed.

You may also want some structural roll up as TYPE is a hierarchy. You would have to use the data model to do this.

It may be that TYPE is already in the facet list ...

It may be that content mimetype gives you more information and is a better choice. Most people do not strongly type documents (which would be a good thing ...)

Andy